# subString emution ios

Tags: ios, arrays, substring

when I try to extract a string :"hello [hihi] wold [hehe]" to array {"hello ","[hihi]","wold","[hehe]","[hehe]"}

```
-(void)getString:(NSString *)emution
{
    int n=[emution length];
    int x=0,y=0,i=0;
    char temp;
    while (true) {
        temp=[emution characterAtIndex:i];
        if(temp == '[')
        {
            x=i;
        }else
        {
            if(temp==']')
            {
                y=i+1;
                NSLog(@"x: %d , y:%d",x,y);
                NSString *sub=[emution substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x, y)];
                NSLog(@"here:%@",sub);
                x=y;
                sub=nil;
            }
            if(i>=n-1)
            {break;}
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

result
it not true i don' undestan but when i try code this with java it is true

Comment: What do you mean, result is not true? There is no result from this void function and no booleans.

Comment: Show the entire log output.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:

```
NSArray *array = [emution componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Also, I'd note that check to end the loop `if(i>=n-1)` should be after you increment `i`, not inside the else statement.